# Different assets for different device configs

Tags: android, webview, android-assets

I'm developing an application which has some assets bundled with it - they are mostly web pages with associated graphics, css etc which I'll display in a custom `WebView`.  I'm trying to work out how to serve up different assets to different devices without massive duplication.

I'd like to replicate the res folder, but for assets. For example:

assets/html/page1.html references assets/html/example_pic.png but I want to serve up a different example_pic.png depending on screen density or screen size.

Ideally I'd like to have something like assets_hdpi/html/example_pic.png and assets_mdpi/html/example_pic.png

Is there an elegant way of achieving this?  Can I somehow utilise the /res/ folder management to the same end result by putting the example_pic.png in to /res/drawable_hdpi etc and then somehow pointing the webpage to the drawable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible workaround:
Prepare a 'subpath' named string for the different resolutions you want to address, e.g.:

`res/values-hdpi/subpath.xml:` <string name="subpath">hdpi</string>

`res/values-ldpi/subpath.xml:` <string name="subpath">ldpi</string>

Prepare corresponding subpaths in your asset folder, e.g.:
`assets/hdpi`, `assets/ldpi` and store your assets there.

Finally, use `getResources.getString(R.string.subpath)` to get the best asset subpath.

```
String AssetPath= "file:///android_asset/"+getResources.getString(R.string.subpath)+"/";
myWebView.loadPage(AssetPath+"index.html");
```